Subspace related to Jordan form
Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and let $\{w_1,\dots,w_r\}$ be the ordinary eigenvectors of $A$ associated with non-trivial Jordan chains, that is, Jordan chains of lenght greater or equal than 2.
My question: Does $\mathrm{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_r\}$ have a standard name?
If not, something like non-diagonalizable, defective, or deficient eigenspace could be appropriate? Any other suggestions?
Example.
Consider the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Matrix $A$ has two ordinary eigenvectors $v_1=[1 \ 0 \ 0]^\top$, $v_2=[0 \ 1 \ 0]^\top$. In this case only $v_2$ is associated with a non-trivial Jordan chain (of length 2), that is, $w_1=v_2$.

Not that I know. You could say "the sum of those eigenspaces which differ from the corresponding characteristic subspaces".
